# trying to play mp4 from cache folder

Tags: objective-c, xcode, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an objective c Xcode project whereby I am showing jpg images on a bunch of iPads.

The images are downloaded at the initiation of my app, and live in the local cache. Images are performing perfectly.

I now need to show video. I am downloading the video mp4 file in the same manner as the jpg's, and am trying to play the video at a certain time. I have tried MPMoviePlayerController, MPMoviePlayerViewController, and AVPlayerController - and all 3 are giving me a black screen or the equivalent. I am under the impression that I am building the path wrong, but cannot prove that.

My Current code is AVPlayer, and here it is:
szFileName is JUST the filename of the mp4 - e.g jpd.mp4

```
NSString *docDir1 = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
     NSURL *movieURL2 = [NSURL URLWithString:[docDir1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:szFileName]];
    NSLog(@"movieURL2:%@", movieURL2);
    NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[docDir1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:szFileName]];
    NSLog(@"movieURL:%@", movieURL);
    NSLog(@"movieURL.absoluteURL:%@", movieURL.absoluteURL);
    NSLog(@"movieURL.:absolutestring%@", movieURL.absoluteString);

    _vcMoviePlayer = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    _vcMoviePlayer.player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:movieURL2];
    _vcMoviePlayer.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    _vcMoviePlayer.showsPlaybackControls = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:_vcMoviePlayer.view];
    self.view.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

Running the above code in simulator it gives me a playback icon with a line through it.

Running it on an iPad give me playback, but a black screen.

Can someone please point me in the right direction to get the correct path/filename combination?